# How can I make STS faster, especially during debug?

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a Roo project deploying to the vfabric tomcat server.  When I run it on the server, it takes five seconds to load.  When I run it on the server to debug it, it takes almost a full minute to load.

I read the thread that suggested turning off validators, but that was for a much older version (2.3.2 and I'm on 3).

Comment: I've tried using the JRockit instead and it's just as slow.  I've tried increasing heap/permgen.  No difference.

Answer (score 1):

If the main problem is with server start time, then the best thing you can do is disable Spring Insight.  It adds a significant amount to startup time.  You can also move to a Eclipse 3.8-based STS.  Eclipse 3.8 is significantly more performant than Eclipse 4.2.